# Jython - attempting to call functions from JFrame, receiving 'NoneType' error

Tags: python, swing, jython

So I'm playing around with Jython, trying to slap together a generic GUI. Nothing beyond what they have on the Jython Wiki for swing examples. So I declare a JFrame, and then try to add a panel, some text fields, all that good stuff. I get this error when I run it, however. "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'"

Here's the basic code I have.

```
from javax.swing import *
frame = JFrame('E-mail Gathering', defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size =(600,400), locationRelativeTo = None).setVisible(True)
pnl = JPanel()
frame.add(pnl)
self.textfield1 = JTextField('username:',15)
pnl.add(self.textfield1)
self.textfield2 = JTextField('password:', 15)
pnl.add(self.textfield2)
mailButton = JButton('Login',actionPerformed=self.checkmail)
pnl.add(mailButton)
frame.pack()
frame.setVisible(True)
```

I know the relevant part where it's crashing is at 'frame.add(pnl)' with the aforementioned error. I figured I'd throw the rest up there just in case I'm making some even greater mistakes. I feel like something's wrong where I'm not declaring frame as a JFrame properly, but I know that's not the case because it creates the frame just fine if I don't try to add anything to it.

Thanks for any advice or suggestions you have.

Comment: You probably know this already, but you shouldn't use `from foo import *` except as shorthand in toy scripts or the interpreter. And even then it's arguably a bad idea.

Comment: I'm actually a total novice, I had no clue. How are you supposed to put it in, and why is the way I'm doing it bad?

Comment: Only import what you need to avoid name collision/ambiguity, for example between `java.util.List` and `java.awt.List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
frame = JFrame('E-mail Gathering', defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size =(600,400), locationRelativeTo = None).setVisible(True)
```

you are creating a `JFrame`, calling its `setVisible` method, and assigning the return value of `setVisible` to `frame`. [`setVisible` doesn't return a value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29), so `frame` is `None`. This causes `frame.add` to fail.

As you call `setVisible` at the end anyway, and because you probably don't want to make the frame visible before you have added other components to it and called `pack`, just remove the `setVisible` call:

```
frame = JFrame('E-mail Gathering', defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size =(600,400), locationRelativeTo = None)
```